# NavigationView DOES NOT register click after removing fragment from main activity layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview

I have the following NavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_vieww09"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="2dp"
    style="@style/calculatorButtonText"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_information"
    />
```

inside onCreate I setup the ItemSelected Listener:

```
 mNavigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            /*String string = item.toString();
            string = string.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");*/
            item.setChecked(true);
            int position = item.getItemId();

            Log.d("taskstodo","the position: " + position);
            if(position > -1/*string.matches("\\d")*/)
                ShowAnySolutions(String.valueOf(position));
            else Log.d("taskstodo","the string did not match a number: " + position);

            mDrawer.closeDrawers();

            return true;
        }

    });
```

When a fragment is added to the main layout, the fragment shows correctly.
Before the fragment is added the clicks work on the NavigationView. But, when I remove the fragment the clicks do not work anymore.

This is how I add the fragment:

```
                FragmentTransaction transaction002 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction002.add(R.id.drawer_layout,graph_fragment);
                transaction002.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction002.commit();
```

This how I remove the fragment, after the user presses a button inside the UI of the fragment layout

```
//inside the button which lies inside the UI of the fragment layout
go_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.os.Message message = new Message();
            message.what = MainActivity.DESTROY_GRAPH_FRAGMENT;
            MainActivity.yes.sendMessage(message);
        }
    });
```

And this how the fragment is removed from the main layout:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction001 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction001.remove(graph_fragment);

                //transaction001.remove(graph_fragment);
                transaction001.commitNow();
```

I am sure it has something to do with the fragment being removed that somehow causes the NavigationView not to register clicks anymore. I am unable to click on an item inside the NavigationView.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the main layout, I noticed that there was a layout included above the NavigationView layout.

So, I believe this layout above caused it to lose focus when removing the fragment

the include layout tag has the layout above:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_vieww09"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:padding="2dp"
style="@style/calculatorButtonText"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_information"
/>

//the layout above
<include layout="@layout/scroll_solve"/>
```

All I had to do was re-arrange the placement within the main layout of the layout 'scroll_solve' AND this fixed the entire problem.

So, make sure that NavigationView is the last view you add in the xml file